# How to display a JPanel inside a JPanel inside a JFrame?

Tags: java

I am trying to display a JPanel class inside a JPanel, that is set inside a JPanel class that is displayed inside a JPanel inside a JFrame class.

Getting the JPanel class to show up in the JFrame class works, but when I try to display another JPanal class inside the first JPanel class, it won't show.

I am using Netbeans 8.2 with the GUI Builder plugin, if there is any better way to get these nested GUI elements to show when needed, I'D appreciate it as well.

The JFrame:

```
public class MitarbeiterUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private javax.swing.JPanel container;

    public MitarbeiterUI(Mitarbeiter mitarbt) {
        initComponents();

        setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        //Auto generated initializer
    }

    private void TarifButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

        TarifDialog dialog = new TarifDialog(this);
        dialog.setVisible(true);

        container.removeAll();
        container.validate();
        container.updateUI();
        container.add(dialog);
    }    

    public void updatePanel(JPanel panel) {
        container.removeAll();
        container.validate();
        container.updateUI();
        container.add(panel);
    } 
}
```

The main JPanel:

```
public class TarifDialog extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    private Boolean sPanelVisible = false;
    private Boolean wPanelVisible = false;
    private Boolean ePanelVisible = false;

    private KontinuierlicherTarifDialog kdialog;      //Nested JDialog class
    private EinmaligerTarifDialog edialog;            //Nested JDialog class
    private MitarbeiterUI parent;

    private javax.swing.JPanel pnContainer;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton rbEinmaligerTarif;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton rbStandardTarif;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton rbWiederkehrenderTarif;

    public TarifDialog(MitarbeiterUI parent) {

        this.parent = parent;
        initComponents();

    }

    private void initComponents() {
        //Auto generated initializer
    }

    private void rbWiederkehrenderTarifStateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {                                                    
        if (rbWiederkehrenderTarif.isSelected() && !wPanelVisible) {
            kdialog = new KontinuierlicherTarifDialog();
            kdialog.setVisible(true);

            pnContainer.removeAll();
            pnContainer.validate();
            pnContainer.updateUI();
            pnContainer.add(kdialog);

            ePanelVisible = false;
            wPanelVisible = true;
            sPanelVisible = false;

            parent.updatePanel(this);

        }
    }                                                   

    private void rbEinmaligerTarifStateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {                                               
        if (rbEinmaligerTarif.isSelected() && !ePanelVisible) {
            edialog = new EinmaligerTarifDialog();
            edialog.setVisible(true);

            pnContainer.removeAll();
            pnContainer.validate();
            pnContainer.updateUI();
            pnContainer.add(edialog);

            ePanelVisible = true;
            wPanelVisible = false;
            sPanelVisible = false;

            parent.updatePanel(this);

        }
    }                                              

    private void rbStandardTarifStateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {                                             
        if (rbStandardTarif.isSelected() && !sPanelVisible) {
            pnContainer.removeAll();
            pnContainer.validate();
            pnContainer.updateUI();

            ePanelVisible = false;
            wPanelVisible = false;
            sPanelVisible = true;

            parent.updatePanel(this);

        }
    } 
}
```

One of the nested FPanel classes:

```
public class EinmaligerTarifDialog extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    public EinmaligerTarifDialog() {
        initComponents();
        this.setVisible((true));
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        //Auto generated initializer
    }
}
```

Comment: They will only show up as soon as you select any radio button. You call `initComponents();` in `TarifDialog`, but that method is not doing anything

Comment: They are supposed to show up when the respective radio buttons are pressed. The `initComponents()` is actually a hundred lines long auto generated and edit protected function setting up the UI part of the class. I just omitted that part for readability.

Comment: So you don't get your new `JPanel`s to show up on `pnContainer`? Then you should try to call `setVisible(true);` **after** adding them to the panel

Comment: Can you specify what layout manager are you using ?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer changing that did nothing sadly.

Comment: @Shrey Trivedi Thanks for the tip! The design of the JPanel of the JFrame class was set to Boarder Layout and the one of the main JPanel class was set to Free Design. Changing it to Boarder Layout did the trick!